# What should I write in version code and version name while updating an android app if I fogot to write it in the 1.0 version?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play, android-manifest

I fogot to write vesion code and version name while uploading 1.0 version of my app to play store.Now I want to give update to it.So,what should  be my version code and version name now?Hope to find help from stackoverflow community.Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `defaultConfig` block of your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `versionName` could be anything, keep it `1.0` since you missed it. Increment `versionCode` by 1.

Comment: So, in my first update to the android app,I need to write versionName=1.0.But, Increment versionCode by 1... I did'nt write it in the first version.So,still I need to write it 2?

Comment: Yes, since it is a string. Keep it in inverted commas `versionName "1.0"`.

Comment: you cant add `=` sign

Comment: You should write 2.

Comment: Thanks @EricB. It should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a new version or first time @Google Play Store App versioning is the main thing.

**Theoretically:**

**versionCode:** On every update, you have to increase with the previous one this is an integer value. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent version of code. So you can't upload a new build with old code version.
This value is not visible to any Google Play Store user.

**Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for versionCode is 2100000000.**

**versionName:** This is not a mandatory part to change in every update, but as it is visible to all the users at the Google Play Store and in the app info. So you should change it's value. This is a string value and has no other purpose than to be displayed to users.

Follow [App versioning](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html)

**Practically:**

Android Studio:-

In the app's build.gradle file, into the android tag

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ...
    }
```

So at the first time by default your versionCode and versionName was like this and you uploaded your build to Play Store for the first time. So for the next update versionCode is mandatory to update in an incremental way and as it is an integer value so always increase its value by 1[Not mandatory by 1 you can keep any number but greater than last one]. So value should be 2.

versionName is visible to user on that behalf users consider their app version. So this should also an upgraded value. Let say now it's "1.0" in next build it should be either "2.0" or "1.1" as per your wish. There is no restriction for it's value.

Answer (score 0):

In your Module level `build.gradle` file put the new version name and code

By default version name is `1.0` and version code is `1`

```
defaultConfig {
        .....
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
```

Comment: So, According to you,though I am giving update to the first version of my app,I need to write version code 1?

Comment: No! by default it is 1 now increment the version code ex `2`

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty clear that versionName is just something that's shown to the user, versionCode is what matter.

you have to increase `VersionCode` for every update in google play

Answer (score 0):

Google Play will complain if you do not include these at all. Android Studio already provides default values when you create a new project. You should just increase `versionCode` by 1 from the current value and `versionName` can be anything you want. Typically, this follows [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

If for some reason, you do not have these values set in your `build.gradle` file, you can add them manually. You can also use the Google Play Developer Console to view their values for the current version.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time, this will be there.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1     // For the first time
        versionName "1.0" // For the first time
    }
```

So, keep in mind that on each update you should change it like this.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2     // Increase it by 1
        versionName "1.1" // Increase it like 0.1
    }
```